# Tool tip customization in share point 2013

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, tooltip

i have a list which constitutes of different fields. On hover of the field currently I see label name and filed validated name. I want to display a new message describing what to fill in that field. And also I want to change the look and feel of the top. Any suggestions are deeply appreciated thanks !!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101737/displaying-field-contents-in-jquery-ui-tooltip

Comment: Not able to relate to my issue . I am not storing the tool tip data in list.

Comment: Is there any js to customize the look of the tool tip as well?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

Use **https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/**
When you build your `HTML (list)`, you have to specify the title attribute for the tooltip text and then jquery ui tool tip will take over by creating tooltip.

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
```